# :-1: error: dependent 'D:\Storage\C++_Libraries\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_32\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib' does not exist

Tags: c++, qt5

A program that I was making in qt5 gave me this error. The program was running fine the previous day. I tried reinstalling the qt library but the problem persisted.

Edit: I checked and the file does not seem to exist. But then, why did it work before? Even my previously completed projects are not working anymore.

Comment: Does the file exist? Is that where your Qt framework is installed? I expect this problem is something you will have to solve.

Comment: ***But then, why did it work before?*** Likely existed before and somehow it was deleted if not by accident perhaps your antivirus or perhaps you changed compilers. Are there other compiler folders in this folder `D:\Storage\C++_Libraries\Qt\5.15.0`?

Comment: Yes, there are other compiler folders there